# How do I rectify a distorted aerial image in QGIS?

Tags: aerial-photography, distortion

When I place an aerial image in QGIS 3.4.15 it becomes distorted (in the attached the left image is correct, the right image is distorted)[image].  How to I rectify this?

Answer (score 1):

The image is being reprojected on-the-fly to the map Coordinate Reference System (*CRS*), which is not the same as the image CRS.

You can change the map CRS with the *Project ~> Properties ~> CRS* setting.

If you tick on *No projection*, all data will be displayed without being reprojected.

Or you can get the raster layer CRS by selecting it and checking the *Layer ~> Layer Properties ~> Information ~> CRS* data. Then you can set the same CRS to the map (project).